# What is this plugin name? (modal exit for wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

in this site, http://www.bitrepository.com/exit-modal-box.html, when you try to leave the page for the first time, a modal is trigered, this is a very well known plugin, its everywhere on the web on wordpress, but I can't find it, I need this exact one because I once saw its backend and it had a ton of options, please help me find it.

Br

Answer (score 0):

Just try  [Easy Modal](http://wizardinternetsolutions.com/plugins/easy-modal/). They have a free version too.

Here is a paid plugins.
[The WordPress Popup System](http://www.wordpresspopupplugin.com/)

Also try this tutorial to do it manually.
[MODAL BOX ON PAGE LOAD WITH JQUERY FANCY BOX AND COOKIE PLUGIN](http://point47.com/journal/2010/06/modal-box-on-page-load-with-jquery-fancy-box-and-cookie-plugin/)